# Find a plane for four points using WolframAlpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

How can you find the plane of four points by WolframAlpha?

Example

```
plane((0,0,0),(2,-1,-1),(4,-2,-2),(8,-4,-4))
```

should give me `x + y + z = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to break it down into pieces and Wolfram does not support combined modules like this.

*Finding the Vectors*

Format : `(2,-1,-1) - (4,-2,-2)`

*Finding the Cross Product*

Format : `{a1,a2,a3} cross {b1,b2,b3}`

Then substitution of one of the points after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by querying

> [plane through (0,0,0),(2,-1,-1),(4,-2,-2),(8,-4,-4)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plane+through+%280%2C0%2C0%29%2C%282%2C-1%2C-1%29%2C%284%2C-2%2C-2%29%2C%288%2C-4%2C-4%29)

Note that the points you've written down are all on a line so don't uniquely define a plane. If instead you give it some points which do uniquely define a plane

> [plane through (0,0,0),(1,0,0),(-1,0,0),(0,1,0)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plane+through+%280%2C0%2C0%29%2C%281%2C0%2C0%29%2C%28-1%2C0%2C0%29%2C%280%2C1%2C0%29)

you get a unique plane as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

This is one of the things you can't be lazy with using Alpha. Solution: [don't be lazy](http://www.jtaylor1142001.net/calcjat/Solutions/VPlanes/VP3Pts.htm) (well, just this once. Spend an hour playing Black Ops to make up for it.)